# Comparing Text Lines in C#

Tags: c#

I want to compare the first line of **text 1** with all the lines of **text 2**, then the second line of text 1 with all the lines of text 2 and so on. Then the common lines of texts will appear!

**Text 1**

1. #John
2. #Gary
3. #Smith

**Text 2**

1. #Adam
2. #James
3. #Gary

The expected result:
**#Gary**

Comment: So, what did you come up with so far? And where are you stuck?

Comment: Use LINQ to resolve your issue. Or post your code here, which you have tried?

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use LINQ for a beginner. Use 2 nested loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is the [intersection of the two sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection) of lines, ie the common items between two sets. It's the same concept taught at high school.

[image]

In .NET you can use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0) to find the intersection/common items between two lists or arrays. To read a file's lines into a `string[]` array you can use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0):

```
var lines1=File.ReadAllLines(path1);
var lines2=File.ReadAllLines(path2);
var commonLines=lines1.Intersect(lines2);

foreach(var line in common)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code gives the expected result.

```
string txt1Path = @"Path_To_Text_File1\Text1.txt",
       txt2Path = @"Path_To_Text_File2\Text2.txt";

       var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(txt1Path);
       var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(txt2Path);
       var res = lines1.Intersect(lines2);
       foreach (var item in res)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item); //Your Result
       }
```